# How can you pass an array of strings to a function as constant in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, constants

I am working on a piece of structured programming homework that requires that I make a program that allows the user to enter names blah blah blah and so on. What I want to do after putting names into the string array is to print them to the screen. I had hoped to accomplish this by passing the array and the number of names contained therein to a function that would then print them to the screen. I wanted to pass the array and number of names as constants so that it would safeguard them so they couldn't be modified by the function, just read-only. I don't understand why I can't put const before the string array or the number of names though.

```
void writeNames (const string namelist[], const int number_of_names)
```

Is this something I just have to accept or is there a way I can pass both of those as read-only to the function? I can complete the homework without this so this is more a question of curiousity than a "help me with my homework" one.

P.S. Vectors seem to be a way of doing a lot more things with strings and such, but we haven't got to them in class yet and therefore I can't use them yet either.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `const` before the array?

Comment: What error are you getting when you include "const"?

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use something that's not been discussed in class?  That seems dumb.

Comment: `error: expected primary-expression before 'const'`


What I'm doing wrong is placing the 'const' modifier in the parameter list of the function _call_ when I should be placing it in the function prototype and function header instead. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you're doing within the function, it's hard to answer the question, but my crystal ball says that you're probably doing something that could potentially modify one of the parameters within your method, so the compiler is complaining because you declared the parameter const.

As an example, something like this works just fine:

```
void writeNames(const std::string namelist[], const int number_of_names)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_names; i++) {
        std::cout << namelist[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, something like this would cause a compiler error, since you're changing one of the variables:

```
void writeNames(const std::string namelist[], const int number_of_names)
{
    while(number_of_names--) {   // <-- We're modifying a const value here
        std::cout << namelist[count] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Incidentally, putting the const modifier on your "number_of_names" parameter is somewhat redundant since you're passing the parameter by value, so changing the value within the function would have no effect on the value of the input parameter in the calling function. A change in any of the strings in the array, however, would be reflected in the calling function, so the const modifier there makes sense. Generally you would use const only on parameters that are either pointers, or being passed in by reference.